# de-duplication function that only keeps the minimum for every 5 sec of previous value

Tags: python, sql

I have a question:

Write a de-duplication function that only keeps the minimum for every 5 sec of previous value

```
0.0 (keep)
2.3 (drop)
4.1 (drop)
5.3 (keep)
7.5 (drop)
8.3 (drop)
10.2 (drop)
11.4 (keep)
```

How do I this is sql and Python in as quick as possible?

Consider this is just some values in a column or an array of values.

I tried this:

```
def de-dup(a):
   output_array=[]
   c=0
   d=a[c]
   while (d<=a[len(a)-1]):
      if a[c]<=d:
        output_array.append(a[c])
      c+=1
      d=a[c]+5
   return output_array
```

Can we do this in sql. I think we can if we can get a cumulative sum of the values but only from previous value and then check the cumulative with the current value and drop.

How does it sound?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  We're here to help, but we won't write your code for you.

Comment: Your sample shows the values, but not the time.  How do you get that information?  And how does SQL fit into this?

Comment: What is Sample output you are looking for? Is the highlighted data available in the database?

Comment: Check edit i added the code

Comment: output would be only values which have "keep" to it

Answer (score 0):

I do know what kind of data you have.
you can add data with time created to the list than compare the latest on with new item.

```
keepLst  = [] 
if not keepLst:
  keepLst.append(item)
else:
  if item.created_time() - keepLst[-1].created_time() > 5:
    keepLst.append(item)
```

or 
you can put your program to sleep for 5 sec then begin to receive data, once get one data sleep again